# While swapping in python using rindex for this specific case why swapping is not happening?

Tags: python-3.x, list

While swapping in python using rindex for this specific case why swapping is not happening? Case-1 is giving correct ans, but not case-2.

Case-1:

```
S=['1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1']
S[S.index('1')], S[''.join(S).rindex('2')] = S[''.join(S).rindex('2')], S[S.index('1')]
print(S)

Output: ['2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Case-2:

```
S=['2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
S[S.index('1')], S[''.join(S).rindex('2')] = S[''.join(S).rindex('2')], S[S.index('1')]
print(S)

Output: ['2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

But Expected `Output: ['1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your indices *before* doing the swap, not in the middle of it:

```
index1, index2 = S.index('1'), ''.join(S).rindex('2')
S[index1], S[index2] = S[index2], S[index1]
```

Comment: But my doubt is why the approach I followed in case-1 or any other cases except the case-2 is working fine. Even in Case-2 if I use index instead of rindex it will swap. Then why not working in this case? If anybody has explaination plz help

Comment: By putting all of the calls to `index` within a statement that changes `S`, you can't be sure when they are being called relative to those changes.